# How to pipeline name/value pair objects to Advanced Function?

Tags: powershell, hash

I have name/value pairs I want to pipe as objects to an Advanced Function.

I'm starting with an OrderedDictionary that looks like this:

```
$jobs = [ordered]@{0='job0';1='job1';2='job2';3='job3';4='job4'; 5='job5';6='job6';}
```

Console output looks like this:

```
$jobs
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                
0                              job0                                                                                                                                                                 
1                              job1                                                                                                                                                                 
2                              job2                                                                                                                                                                 
3                              job3                                                                                                                                                                 
4                              job4                                                                                                                                                                 
5                              job5                                                                                                                                                                 
6                              job6
```

The function looks like this:

```
Function Process-Jobs {
   [cmdletbinding()]
   Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][hashtable]$jobs
   )
    Begin {
        Write-Output '--> begin block <--'
    }
    Process {
        Write-Output $_.Name
        Write-Output $_.Value
    }
    End {
        Write-Output '--> end block <--'
    }
}
$jobs = [ordered]@{0='job0';1='job1';2='job2';3='job3';4='job4'; 5='job5';6='job6';}
$jobs | Process-Jobs
```

The above code does not work and returns this to the console:

```
--> begin block <--
--> end block <--
```

I tried making the hash table a custom object like this:

```
$jobs = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{0='job0';1='job1';2='job2';3='job3';4='job4'; 5='job5';6='job6';}
```

Console output looks like this:

```
$jobs
0 : job0
1 : job1
2 : job2
3 : job3
4 : job4
5 : job5
6 : job6
```

If I modify the function...

```
Function Process-Jobs {
   [cmdletbinding()]
   Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][PSCustomObject]$jobs
   )
    Begin {
        Write-Output '--> begin block <--'
    }
    Process {
        $i = 0
        Write-Output $jobs.Name
        Write-Output $jobs.$i
    }
    End {
        Write-Output '--> end block <--'
    }
}

$jobs = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{0='job0';1='job1';2='job2';3='job3';4='job4'; 5='job5';6='job6';}
$jobs | Process-Jobs
```

Console output looks like this:

```
--> begin block <--
job0
--> end block <--
```

It seems I've lost the ability to reference the Name property.

How do I access the Name property of the `$jobs` object?

I start with the OrderedDictionary because I need it for processing elsewhere in the function.

Is there a better way to pipe name/value pairs to an Advanced Function?

Should I use something like this:

```
$jobs = New-Object –TypeName PSCustomObject
$jobs | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name 'Name' –Value 0
$jobs | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name 'Value' –Value 'job0'
...
$jobs | Process-Jobs
```

will need additional code to loop and sort...

Comment: `$jobs.GetEnumerator() | Process-Jobs`

Comment: This works:`Function Process-Jobs {
   [cmdletbinding()]
   Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$NameValue
   )
    Begin {
        Write-Output '--> begin block <--'
    }
    Process {

        "name = $($NameValue.Name), value = $($NameValue.Value)"
    }
    End {
        Write-Output '--> end block <--'
    }
}
$jobs = [ordered]@{0='job0';1='job1';2='job2';3='job3';4='job4'; 5='job5';6='job6';}
$jobs.GetEnumerator() | Process-Jobs`